# Showing an orthogonalisation process

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Can anyone show that:

$\mathbf{a_{\perp}}=\mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}$,

$\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $\mathbf{x}=(1,1,\dots,1)^T\in\mathbb{R}^N$

results in $\mathbf{a}$ becoming orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be $$\mathbf{a}_\perp=\mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}$$

Comment: The question seems to be ill-posed, since you're definition is simple $\;a=a-1\cdot a=0\;$ ...This will be orthogonal with *everything*

Comment: @DonAntonio It seems to me that the expression used is wrong.

Comment: Just updated the expression, my mistake.

Comment: @dandaniels56446 I still see something very wrong in your question... This seems to be connected with Gram Schmidt process.

Comment: What else is wrong? What is the Gram Schmidt process?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left(\mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}\right)\cdot \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}^T\frac{\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}=0$$

Refer also to the related

- [Writing projection in terms of projection matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2716442/505767)
- [orthogonal projection from one vector onto another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893502/505767)